# issue with hover on nth-child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm creating a news section for a website with 4 tiles for each article. Odd tiles have a darker blue background-color and the even tiles have a lighter blue. (dark-light-dark-light)

Now I want to add a `:hover` effect where the element gets a slightly lighter color than its' default value. So the odd and dark-blue tiles get a slightly lighter color and the even and light-blue tiles get an even lighter blue color when this happens.

I have a problem with this hover effect though. So if I hover on the first tile (odd) it adds the `:hover` effect on the 3rd (also odd) tile as well.

How to do this for just the one I am hovering on?

```css
.tile-text {
        width: 100%;
        height: 25%;
        display: table;
        background: #337AB7;
        color: #EFEFEF;
    }
    
    .top-tiles a:nth-of-type(odd) .tile-text {
     background: #304770;
    }
    
    .top-tiles:hover a:nth-of-type(odd) .tile-text {
     background: orange; //just test-colors
    }
    
    .tile:hover .tile-text {
     background-color: red; //just test-colors
    }
    
    .tile-text div {
     display: table-cell;
     vertical-align: middle;
     font-size: 20px;
    }
```

```html
    <section class="top-tiles">
  <a href="#">
   <div class="tile">
    <div class="tile-pic" style="background-image:url('');"></div>
    <div class="tile-text"><div>Sample text</div></div>
   </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
   <div class="tile">
    <div class="tile-pic" style="background-image:url('');"></div>
    <div class="tile-text"><div>Sample text</div></div>
   </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
   <div class="tile">
    <div class="tile-pic" style="background-image:url('');"></div>
    <div class="tile-text"><div>Sample text</div></div>
   </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
   <div class="tile">
    <div class="tile-pic" style="background-image:url('');"></div>
    <div class="tile-text"><div>Sample text</div></div>
   </div>
  </a>
 </section>
```

As a side question, I also noticed that if I remove this:

```
.top-tiles:hover a:nth-of-type(odd) .tile-text {
    background: orange; //just test-colors
}
```

then `.tile:hover .tile-text` only applies to the even-tiles. Why doesn't it apply to odd tiles as well?

Thanks!

Comment: With `.tile:hover .tile-text` you apply the style when hovered on `.tile` to all .tile-text children, I think you want something like `.tile .tile-text:hover`

Comment: @Me.Name, but wouldn't that only apply when the cursor is over the `title-text` div? I want the effect to happen when mouse-over anywhere on the tile (picture or text).

Comment: As you are hovering on complete container that's why you are getting selection on all odd/even children.

Comment: @Cris, sorry was mixing up .top-tiles and . tile, using `.tile:hover .tile-text` should work. Vann's answer shows the proper override for when using n-th tile :)

Comment: @Me.Name sure thing. ty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing your css to this:

```
.tile-text {
    width: 100%;
    height: 25%;
    display: table;
    background: #337AB7;
    color: #EFEFEF;
}

.top-tiles a:nth-of-type(odd) .tile-text {
    background: #304770;
}

.top-tiles a:nth-of-type(odd):hover .tile-text {
    background: orange; //just test-colors
}

.top-tiles a:nth-of-type(even):hover .tile-text {
    background-color: red; //just test-colors
}

.tile-text div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: I am glad. Could you Accept it?

Answer (score 3):

you problem lies here:

```
.top-tiles:hover a:nth-of-type(odd) .tile-text {
    background: orange; //just test-colors
}
```

whenever you hover your `.top-tiles` it will apply orange to every odd tile inside that element.

What you want is to add orange background whenever you hover only odd tile like this:

```
.top-tiles a:nth-of-type(odd):hover .tile-text {
    background: orange; //just test-colors
}
```